# What is written in this excerpt from a Manifest of Alien Passengers for the US arriving at Providence?

Tags: united-states, palaeography, immigration, 1910s

I'm having difficulties reading a field from a specific column from a

> List or Manifest of Alien Passengers for the United States Immigration
>   Officer at Port of Arrival

In this case Port of Providence. Year of arrival: 1917.

The title of the column I'm interested in is

> 18 - Whether going to join a relative or a friend; and if so, what
>   relative or friend, and his name and complete address?

And the handwritten text is

[image]

EDIT:

Zooming in the same text I can discern no `h` in `Teresa` (the correct spelling in Portuguese).

And I'm still in doubt between `Teixeira` and `Ferreira`

[image]

Answer (score 6):

It appears to read:

> Female cousin. Theresa C. Te?r?eira
>   868 Broad Street. Central Falls

where the ? might be j or f

There is a Theresa Kelly Feireira in the Rhode Island marriages.

Comment: Thanks. The `Te?r?eira`helped me arrive at `Ferreira`. And I think It's `Teresa`

Comment: Any explanation why the `T` from `Theresa` is so different from the `T` from `Te?r?eira`?

Answer (score 4):

> Female cousin, Thereza C. Teixeira
>   868 Broad Street, Central Falls

I would suggest searching the available censuses and directories to determine who was living at this address around this time.

Comment: Looks like the `S` in `Street` is messing with the `T`. Are you sure about `Thereza`? I'm almost sure this person left the US before the 1920 Census, and in the 1910 Census wasn't there yet.

Comment: I am fairly confident the surname is not Feirreira, I think Teixeira much more likely. The first name is written Thereza although that could easily be spelled Teresa or Theresa in other records. Can you find any passenger lists for the cousin?

Comment: I'm aware the names were transmitted orally, and that the person writing the manifest tended to anglicize the names. In this case I'm interested first in the paleographic reading, and then I'll do the work to revert to the original language. Now I'm trying to understand why there was no `868`  in `Broad Street" 3 years after the arrival. http://us-census.org/pub/usgenweb/census/ri/providence/1920/076-014a.txt

Comment: Bear in mind that the information on the big sheets has been copied at least once. The clerk writing the manifest was copying the information from an intake sheet, which may have been written by another clerk or the person purchasing the ticket (not necessarily the passenger).  The ticket buyer may have dictated the information to a clerk.

Answer (score 3):

There is a Treza Ferreira recorded in the census in Trenton Street, Providence in 1920, who stated that she immigrated in 1916. https://www.familysearch.org/ark:/61903/3:1:33S7-9RX3-96S?i=18&cc=1488411&personaUrl=%2Fark%3A%2F61903%2F1%3A1%3AMJKS-SZC

Comment: Thank you. Where did the `Trenton Street` came from? I can see `Providence Ward 1` but no specific Street name.

Comment: It is written vertically in the first column of the table.