# Alien Passenger (1917) who became Relative to be joined (1920): how to reconcile address discrepancies?

Tags: united-states, immigration, 1910s, 1920s, rhode-island

From a previous [question](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/16000/what-is-written-in-this-excerpt-from-a-manifest-of-alien-passengers-for-the-us-a) it was noted that a certain Alien Passenger arriving at Providence RI in 1917, gave as an Address of a female cousin to be joined:

> 868 Broad Street, Central Falls

From another two columns (`State` and `City or Town`) from the same Manifest we have:

[image]

The interpretation I make is

> Rhode Island

and

> Central Falls

respectively. Please note that the `Central` looks like it was corrected (`C.` replaced by `Central`?).

Three years later (in 1920) the sister of the mentioned Alien Passenger arrived also at Providence (let's call her Alien Passenger II).

[image]

So, we have again a

> Broad Street

but this time in

> Valley Falls

Rhode Island.

There is also a number (?) in the end of the first line that is imperceptible to me.

One reference I could find for Valley Falls is

> The Valley Falls Mill is a historic textile mill complex on Broad
>   Street in Central Falls, Rhode Island
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valley_Falls_Mill

`Broad Street` and `Central Falls`, again.

Are we talking about the same address? The same place in Rhode Island? The mentioned imperceptible number, what does it mean? And `Central` being corrected?

Comment: The number looks like "125". The "2" is higher up than the other numbers and close to the "1", and there is a check mark below the "5".

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to dive into the 1920 Federal Census to see what comes up.